# Multiple columns in theorem

Tags: multicol, amsthm, thmtools

I use `amsthm` and `thmtools` and I want to specify 2 columns in my theorem. I have 2 questions:

1. When I specify it, I obtain a very bad result (there is an issue to break correctly the text)
2. Is there any possibility to declare the two columns direclty in `\declaretheorem`?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{hyperref,nameref}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\declaretheoremstyle[
spaceabove=6pt,
spacebelow=6pt,
headfont=\normalfont\bfseries,
notefont=\em\mdseries,
notebraces={(}{)},
headpunct={},
bodyfont=,%\itshape,
headindent=15pt,
headformat=\NAME\,\textcolor{red}{\NUMBER}\NOTE%\\
]{solution}

\declaretheorem[% 
style=solution,
numbered=yes,%unless unique,
name=Solution,
refname={solution,solution},
Refname={Solution,Solutions},
thmbox=L,%
]{solution}


\begin{document}

\begin{solution}
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum{10}
    \end{multicols}
\end{solution}


\end{document}
```

**EDIT:**

For the 2nd question, the solution is

```
\declaretheorem[% 
style=solution,
numbered=yes,%unless unique,
name=Solution,
% numberwithin=exercise,
refname={solution,solution},
Refname={Solution,Solutions},
thmbox=L,%
postheadhook=\begin{multicols}{2},
prefoothook=\end{multicols}
]{solution}
```

But breakline remains wrong

Comment: The problems you're talking about are the page breaks? Your solutions should span more than one page?

Comment: @Vincent Yes, it is.